# For each row, select all instances where value is not '0' (in any/all columns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks something like this:

```
   Col1    Col2   Col3    ColN
   0       0      2       1
   10      5      0       8
   0       0      0       12
```

Trying to get a sum/mean of all the times a value has not been zero, for each row (and then add it as a 'Sum/Mean' column), to have output:

```
   Col1    Col2   Col3    ColN    Sum
   0       0      2       1       2
   10      5      0       8       1
   0       0      0       12      3
```

In the df, I'm recording number of times an event has occurred. I'm trying to get the average number of occurrences or frequency (or I guess, the number of times a value in a row has been not 0).

Is there some way to apply this dataframe-wide? I have about 2000 rows, and have been hacking away trying to use Counter but have managed to get the number of times something has been observed only for 1 row :(

Or maybe I should convert all non-zero numbers to a dummy variable, but then still don't know how to select and sum?

Comment: Could you share the expected output?

Comment: You need `df.ne(0).sum(1)`?

Comment: Yatu, bless your soul, that absolutely is what I was looking for! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

As yatu suggested,

```
df.ne(0).sum(1)
```

does the job. (Note: when I use it to do df['Sum'] = df.ne(0).sum(1), I get a warning message, but I don't really understand the implications)

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Actually, I get several rows with zeroes in the wanted column that are still there (not sure why), so I also go and remove any rows with zeroes after this (this is all very ugly, but no idea...)

```
df = df[(df[['Sum']] != 0).all(axis=1)]
```